# A lengths() sugar function in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

In base R, the lengths() function computes the length of each element within a list. For example,

```
> mylist = list(v1 = c(1,2,3), v2 = c(1,2), v3 = c(1,2,3,4))
> mylist
$`v1`
[1] 1 2 3

$v2
[1] 1 2

$v3
[1] 1 2 3 4

> lengths(mylist)
v1 v2 v3 
 3  2  4
```

Is there an equivalent function like this in Rcpp (or from Armadillo)? I know one can write an Rcpp based apply() function, but I would like to optimize my speed at this step. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about an equivalent sugar function, so would be keen to know if one exists too. And I know you say you can write your own, but I'll throw my hat into the ring with these two functions I use. One is recursive, so it determines the size of each sub-list element, and the other is an equivalent to `lengths()` (non-recursive).

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(

  code = 'Rcpp::List rcpp_lengths_recursive( const Rcpp::List& lst ) {
  std::size_t n = lst.size();
  Rcpp::List res( n ); 
  std::size_t i;

  for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    switch( TYPEOF( lst[i] ) ) {
      case VECSXP: {
        // might need an `Rf_inherits( lst[i], "data.frame" )` check, 
        // depending on your use-case
        res[ i ] = rcpp_lengths_recursive( lst[i] );
        break;
      }
      default: {
        int n_elements = Rf_length( lst[i] );
        res[i] = n_elements;
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}'

)

cppFunction(

  code = 'Rcpp::IntegerVector rcpp_lengths( const Rcpp::List& lst ) {
    std::size_t n = lst.size();
    Rcpp::IntegerVector res( n );
    std::size_t i;

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
      res[i] = Rf_length( lst[i] );
    }
    return res;
  }'

)

mylist <- list(v1 = c(1,2,3), v2 = c(1,2), v3 = list(list(c(1,2,3,4)), 1:2))

rcpp_lengths( mylist )
# [1] 3 2 2

rcpp_lengths_recursive( mylist )
# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# [[3]][[1]][[1]]
# [1] 4
# 
# 
# [[3]][[2]]
# [1] 2
```